# In Javascript, how do I use .filter to return objects that have a property that contains a string?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that returns everything I expect it to

```
let discs = Discrepancies.filter(function(disc) {
  return disc.defect.toLowerCase() == def.id.toLowerCase();   
});
```

however, now I would like to change this to return all results that contain a substring. For example:

```
disc.defect.toLowerCase = 'loose fastener'
```

and I want to return all `def.id.toLowerCase()` if it contains the substring `'loose'`.

How do I accomplish this?

I tried `include` but it doesn't seem to work for me. I'm using IE 11.

Comment: [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) is not suppoerted in IE, so use one of the other methods listed in the duplicate, e.g. `return disc.defect.toLowerCase().indexOf('loose') !== -1`, or use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Polyfill) for browsers that don't implement `includes`.

Comment: that's it.  i'd give you credit if you post it as an answer.  thanks muchly!

Comment: There is no need to post that as an answer because it was already answered in the linked duplicate (and most likely in other similar questions too). The comment and the possible answer I could write would not provide any new information. As of that, it is sufficient and better to just leave it marked as duplicate.